# Problem with button which must change the color in Android Studio

Tags: android, button, kotlin

Could you please describe the logic of a program in Android (Kotlin), where one click changes the color, and then another click on the same button changes the color back?
The lecturer did it by using Boolean but I can not do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that the button's background is a color and not some other drawable then:

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    button.setBackgroundColor(if ((button.background as ColorDrawable).color == Color.RED) Color.GREEN else Color.RED) 
}
```

change `button` to the id of your `Button` and `Color.GREEN` and `Color.RED` to the colors you want.